# need help php global date and time is not local date time

Tags: php, date, time

```
$info = getdate(); 
$year = $info['year']; 
echo date($year); 
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul')); 
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul')) 
echo $now->format("Y")
```

I need help. The server date must remain the same when I change the local date. Server changes date when local date changes.

Comment: `date($year)` The argument to `date()` should be a format string, `$year` is a number.

Comment: I don't understand the question. All PHP date functions deal with server time.

Comment: when I change the date settings of my local machine, for example 11.13.2017.I want the date settings in my php file on the server to give today's date 11.13.2018 The code block above gives the date of my local machine

Comment: I can't think of any way that could be happening unless you're using your local machine as the server.

Comment: If I use my local machine as a server, how can I check the date status? thanks

Comment: A machine only has one date. If the server and client are the same machine, then the local time and server time are the same.

Comment: If you want to be able to see the difference, you need to use different client and server.